# What's the flaw in "collapsed rounding"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rounding-error

A couple of years ago, I asked my high school math teacher the following question and she couldn't give me an answer. I had since forgotten about it, but now I'm curious to find the answer again.

Let's say I have the number `1.49`. Now, obviously rounding this to the nearest integer would yield the result of `1`. But if I were to first round it to the nearest tenths place, I'd get `1.5`, and rounding that results in `2`. Even as someone who's not very well-versed in Mathematics, I can tell you that this is incorrect. My question is *why*? What's wrong with rounding this way. I get the practical reasons, like this is increasing the margin of error for something like taxes, but are there any mathematical reasons as to why this is incorrect?

Comment: Successive rounding could even take you from $1.4444445$ to $2$

Comment: Rounding gives rise to all sorts of mathematical oddities.  Read about the [Alabama Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_paradox) for a serious, real world example.

Comment: FYI, here is a related question that has a lot more references and description of the "double rounding" problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599772/19658

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you round to the nearest integer you guarantee that the correct value is within $\pm 0.5$ of your rounded value.  You have demonstrated that collapsed rounding violates this.